# Node.js Installation Errors on Mac OSX: [Errno 13] Permission Denied error

Tags: node.js, installation

I am trying to install node.js on Mac OSX.

I'm following this guide:

http://theoutliers.com/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-mac-osx/

I'm currently at the "make" step. but I get an error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission Denied error: '/usr/local/include/node/'
```

1. Where is this directory on my computer?
2. How do I grant permission?

I know these are elementary questions, but like I said, I'm learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Where is this on my computer**
The `/usr` directory is hidden in OS X. You will have to enable hidden files, or you can use Command + Shift + G from Finder to go there. Screenshot: http://o7.no/oaQCDL

**2) How do I grant permission**
You can either go there in Finder, right-click and choose `Show Info`, select the `Permissions` area, and change to permissions that would allow your user to Write, for example: 775. Alternatively you can run the command `sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/include/node`. To grant permission temporary you can run make with `sudo make install` and enter your password. That will give the `make` process root permissions to install Node.js there.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the excellent homebrew package manager for Mac OS X. The following post shows you how to install homebrew and use it to Install node.js:

http://vivahate.com/2010/10/10/node-os-mac-os-x/

Hope this helps

Comment: Please update or remove link (upvoted after/instead of downvoted because old post).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the make/make install as root. (Only if you trust the source)

Simply invoke the comand like `sudo make` or `sudo make install` and enter your password.

Otherwise, you could own the directory that fails, but since /usr/local/include is not obviously in your "possession", I'd stick to being superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Either install as root as @iStefo suggests (perhaps slightly safer to run `make install` as yourself and let the install fail and thrn run `make install` as root qhich will just do the install)

or change the install directory which you do when running ./configure (run ./configure --help to hopefully show you the parameter to use)

Alternatively install C libraries and packages using a package manager e.g. macports, fink, homebrew